# Java WebSocket client memory leak

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, httpclient, spring-websocket

I have an application that runs multiple client socket connections. I've noticed that when I send thousands of messages simultaneously, it occasionally generates a memory leak. What could it depend on? Could it be a network problem? Bottleneck?

I'll try to slow down the process of a single message but it is a workaround.

A note: when I run a command GC manually then Garbage Collector frees the memory otherwise it grows constantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why have multiple websockets? why not a single websocket with multiple message types?

Comment: the application is like this by design because for each connection I send chunks that build a single file

Comment: This could be done with a single websocket with chunks being sent for different message types (topics) building a single file for each message type. Are you aware that browsers have a limit of the number of websockets per domain? At some point you might reach that limit with your design

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong. It is the websocket server job to build the file. I have another server that communicates with the ws server creating multiple client connections. I don't communicate via browser calls but via Artemis calls. It's a rather complex architecture

Comment: ah... I'm guessing many people would assume a browser based client when discussing websockets

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was getting memory leaks when using `spring-websocket`. I'm not sure if the issue was with spring or with tomcat.

I ended up switching to `spring-webflux` which uses `netty` under the hood. I haven't had any issues since the move to `spring-webflux`. Note that the API's are quite different for `webflux` which uses reactive streams.